# Pandas : How to flatten/split multiple nested dictionary, inside a JSONresponse

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting a `json` response like this :

```
{
            "id": 7,
            "status": "Public",
            "Options": [
                  {
                        "id": 8,
                        "pId": 7
                  },
                  {
                      "id": 9,
                        "pId": 10
                  }
               ]
}
```

and i am trying to flatten it using `pandas dataframe`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(response_data)

#spliting production options
df=df.join(pd.DataFrame(df["Options"].values.tolist()).add_prefix('Options_'))
df = df.drop(columns=["Options"])

#spliting nested product options
df=df.join(pd.DataFrame(df["Options_0"].values.tolist()).add_prefix('Options0_'))
df = df.drop(columns=["Options_0"])
```

This code used to work when the response only had one `Options`

```
{
            "id": 7,
            "status": "Public",
            "Options": [
                  {
                        "id": 8,
                        "pId": 7
                  }
              ]
}
```

Now there are multiple `Options` inside the json response,
How to iterate this and get smthing like this

```
id   status   Options_0_id  Options_0_pId    Options_1_id  Options_2_pId
7     Public     8                  7           9            10
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's get the **id** and **pId** values ​​into a list using the group by function.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(response_data)
df=df.rename(columns={'id':'id_main'})
df=df.join(pd.json_normalize(df.pop('Options')))
df=df.groupby('id_main').agg({'status':'first','id':list,'pId':list})
print(df)
'''
         status      id      pId
id_main                         
7        Public      [8, 9]  [7, 10]
'''
```

Now we will convert the id and pId columns into a separate dataframe and merge them with df at the end.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(df.id.tolist(), index= df.index).rename('Options_{}_id'.format, axis=1)
print(a)
'''
         Options_0_id  Options_1_id
id_main                            
7                   8             9
'''

#Let's do the same for the pId column.
b=  pd.DataFrame(df.pId.tolist(), index= df.index).rename('Options_{}_pId'.format, axis=1)
print(b)
'''
         Options_0_pId  Options_1_pId
id_main                              
7                    7             10
'''
```

Finally, let's put it all together

```
df=df.join([a,b]).drop(['id','pId'],axis=1).reset_index()
print(df)
'''
id_main status  Options_0_id    Options_1_id    Options_0_pId   Options_1_pId
7       Public  8               9               7               10

'''
```

if you want to sort the columns as in the question:

```
df=df.set_index(['id_main','status'])
df = df.sort_index(axis=1).reset_index()
print(df)
'''
   id_main  status  Options_0_id  Options_0_pId  Options_1_id  Options_1_pId
0        7  Public             8              7             9             10
'''
```

also you can rename id_main:

```
df=df.rename(columns={'id_main':'id'})
```